# merge multiple json file into one python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to merge multiple json file into one that looks like this:

```
file1: [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]
file2: [[g,h],[i,f],[k,l]]
file3: [[m,n],[o,p],[q,r]]
```

I am using this code to merge the files:

```
data = []
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f,) as infile:
        data.append(json.load(infile))

with open("merged_file.json",'w') as outfile:
  json.dump(data, outfile)

out:  [[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]],[[g,h],[i,f],[k,l]],[[m,n],[o,p],[q,r]]]
```

But what I really need is this:

```
[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],[g,h],[i,f],[k,l],[m,n],[o,p],[q,r]]
```

Instead of having separated lists, I need all the pairs in one list.

Hope someone can help me, cheers!

Comment: use `extend` instead of `append` - `data.extend(json.load(infile))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure all files become `list`s after `json.load`-ing you might replace:

```
data.append(json.load(infile))
```

with

```
data.extend(json.load(infile))
```

Which should produce desired result.